# Javamail hangs when sending mail

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

So basically i'm having a problem when using javamail to send mail. It blocks and does not generate an exception. I've tried to put the debug to true and here the messages that i get:

```
DEBUG: not loading system providers in <java.home>/lib
DEBUG: not loading optional custom providers file: /META-INF/javamail.providers
DEBUG: successfully loaded default providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.S    MTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc],   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.
SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc],  com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLSto    re,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLSto    re,Sun M
icrosystems, Inc],     com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun     Microsystems, Inc],     com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun   Microsystems, Inc]}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol:     {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems,     Inc], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems,     Inc], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,
smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc],     pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc],     pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun Microsystems,     Inc], smtp=java
x.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]}
DEBUG: not loading optional address map file: /META-INF/javamail.address.map
```

It does not go further and hangs in here.

I k now for a fact that the next message to be shown would be

```
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
```

But i don't understand whats going on. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It could be a communication problem with the SMTP server.  Take a stack dump and see what it is doing.

Comment: Did you try to set a breakpoint and step into the sendMail?
Also is it possible that the mail is large, because sendMail is blocking until transfer is complete.

Comment: So a litlle more detail. i having a working version in different machine working, using the same mail server and code. That's how i could see what would be the next message. So i'm more inclined to a configuration issue of this machine, or something like this.

Comment: @hugob0ss, SMTP is a text protocol.  To help reduce the possibilities, Telnet to the server and send the mail command by hand.  An example can be seen towards the bottom of https://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/PERL/node175.html

Comment: This is a duplicate of the message you posted [here](https://community.oracle.com/message/12555952#12555952).